# How to retrieve videos from Instagram Python client?

Tags: python, api, video, client, instagram

I'm using [Python Instagram Client](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) to retrieve data from Instagram. I have created an Instagram account for testing purposes where I have three media content: two images and one video. After making a request using Python Instagram Client using python console, I get next response (django shell):

```
>>> recent_media, next = api.user_recent_media()
>>> recent_media
>>> [Media: 673901579909298365_1166496117, Media: 673880146437045009_1166496117, Media: 673827880594143995_1166496117]
```

I have inspected all the media objects, and there is no video information in them, in spite of last media object being a video. All three objects return an attribute called `images`; last media object, despite being a video as I said before, has also an `images` attribute with a video snapshot in different resolutions. After reading Instagram Rest API, my understanding is last Media object should have an attribute called `videos`, which would be a dict, and video information would be there (basically I'm interested in retrieving videos' urls).

My question is: is Python Instagram Client outdated so it returns no video information at all and I have to use the rest api to get video info? Or am I doing something wrong in my requests?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The Python API for Instagram is full of missing features and bugs. I've fixed them on my own local version, but I haven't pushed anything to the official github and I am not sure they would accept the changes.

What is happening in general is their API client is stripping out data when it converts things back to a model. Why they didn't just use something that would convert dictionaries to dot notation models, I am unsure. It's completely manually and full of mistakes/bad Python IMO. Anyway, the gist is that the data is all there, but they are ignoring it when converting from dictionaries into their proprietary API models.

Here is what I found is problematic for what you are trying to do:

1. No "type" information is returned in the API media model. There is a "type" property that you can check for any media related response to see if it is an image or video. You can add this yourself as I did, or you can try to just assume that anything you get that has a "videos" section with populated data is a video.
2. No "videos" information is returned with an API media model. I also just added this myself. There are two URLs you can use which you can see if you look at the json, one for standard resolution and one for low resolution. When you process the response, these properties aren't always there so your code should make checks with get/getattr/etc. accordingly.
3. The paging information in the API is also broken IMO. You are supposed to get back an object with a few different pieces of information, part of which they claim is deprecated (why they are inflating the response at the same version endpoint with this info, I have no idea). The only piece of information you get back here is the next url for paging, which is completely useless in the python API client. There is no reason to get back a REST URL that you would have to manually call and parse outside the API when the whole reason you're using the python client is to avoid that. Anyway, what you will need to do is patch the API client to again send you back the proper models for this or simply parse it out of the URL. I chose to do the latter originally because originally I hoped to not patch the client itself. You'll run into an additional problem because some end points such as tags actually change the querystring parameters in the paging url you get back, so you'll have to conditionally check what they give you. Again, the design is inconsistent and that's not a good thing IMO.

I can post code for all of this if you like, but if you want to try to find a more elegant way to patch all this, you want to look in I believe models.py in the API. I'm not in front of the code right now, but here's what I did from memory.

1. Create a new video model that inherits from the media model, as they did for the image model.
2. Where they read the response dictionary, parse out the videos and add them to the response dictionary as they did the images. Remember to add a pre-condition to check if the videos key is missing as I mentioned earlier.
3. Parse the type property and add it to the response model.
4. Add a model for the paging data and parse it out into the model. Alternatively, just wrap this via some querystring parsing in your own code if you prefer.

If you do all the above, you should be able to simply read a "videos" property and get the 2 video URLs. That's it. The information is always coming back in the response, just remember they are dropping it in the code. I'm happy to provide code\more info if you like.

Edit: Here's some code - put in models.py in object_from_dictionary in the API:

```
    #add the videos
    if "videos" in entry:
        new_media.videos = {}
        for version, version_info in entry['videos'].iteritems():
            new_media.videos[version] = Video.object_from_dictionary(version_info)
    #add the type
    new_media.type = entry.get('type')


    #Add this class as well for the videos....
    class Video(ApiModel):

    def __init__(self, url, width, height):
       self.url = url
       self.height = height
       self.width = width

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Video: %s" % self.url
```